# Scrollview just show my last array's element in view which i create with storyboard in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, view, scrollview

I want to add a few view in scrollview. But I dont want to this view programmatically. I want to create with storyboard. This view include an image. I added scrollview and added to view. But in scrollview I just showing my last view. I want to 2 view and 2 image like my view. *How can i fix this?*

This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mainScrollView: UIScrollView!
var imageArray = [UIImage]()
@IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var imgv: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imageArray = ["image","image2"]

    for i in 0..<imageArray.count{
        mainScrollView.contentSize.width = mainScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
        myView.layer.frame.size.width = myView.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)

        imgv.image = imageArray[i]
        mainScrollView.addSubview(myView)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
```

This is storyboard and controller looks [like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUdG7.png)

Comment: Have you considered using a collection view for this layout?

Answer (score 0):

You are having an issue with constraints from what I see and that is why you might not see every element that you put on your storyboard. You need to correct those errors for everything to show up correctly in your scrollview. Keep in mind, you need to tell the scrollview what its height and width should be in the storyboard. They need to be defined in some way. This is a common mistake when working with scrollviews.

You can put a view in your scrollview and define its height and width property. You can set its width to be equal to the screen's width and you can set a constant for your height.

Comment: When I fix these its not working too. Also scrollview not scroll.

Comment: Can you give me a little more context on what you are trying to do. I am not exactly sure. You do need to make sure there are not red constraints in the storyboard. That will generally cause issues at runtime.